# How to produce an array of objects grouped by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping

Given an array of objects with some common properties like `foosWithBar`, how can I create another array of objects grouped by those common properties like `barsWithFoos` without using libraries like lodash? I've found [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key) that create an object grouped by key using `reduce()`, but that is not quite what I want.

```
const foosWithBar = [
  {
    id: 'Foo A',
    bar: {
      id: 'Bar 1',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 'Foo B',
    bar: {
      id: 'Bar 1',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 'Foo C',
    bar: {
      id: 'Bar 2',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 'Foo D',
    bar: {
      id: 'Bar 2',
    },
  },
]

const barsWithFoos = [
  {
    id: 'Bar 1',
    foos: [
      {
        id: 'Foo A',
      },
      {
        id: 'Foo B',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'Bar 2',
    foos: [
      {
        id: 'Foo C',
      },
      {
        id: 'Foo D',
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Comment: _"create an object grouped by key ... but that is not quite what I want."_ - Why is this not what you want? The _"key"_ in this case is the value in `bar.id`.

Comment: And this has nothing to do with `json`

Comment: Are you saying transform `foosWithBar` into `barsWithFoos`? What have you tried so far? You're expected to at least try and we can help if you have issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reduce to move it into a new format. Using an object to keep track of the  "bars" that you already referenced. You than use Object.values, to get your array.

```js
const foosWithBar = [
  { id: 'Foo A', bar: { id: 'Bar 1', }, },
  { id: 'Foo B', bar: { id: 'Bar 1', }, },
  { id: 'Foo C', bar: { id: 'Bar 2', }, },
  { id: 'Foo D', bar: { id: 'Bar 2', }, },
];

const opposite = Object.values(
  foosWithBar.reduce(
    function(acc, item) {
      if (!acc[item.bar.id]) { // have we seen it yet?
        acc[item.bar.id] = { // if not create the object
          id: item.bar.id,
          foos: [{
            id: item.id
          }]
        };
      } else { // if we seen it, just add the new foo
        acc[item.bar.id].foos.push({
            id: item.id
        });
      }
      return acc;
    }, {})
);
console.log(opposite);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate each `foo` item and search it in the `barsWithFoos` array. If it isn't there, you will need to include it with `barsWithFoos.push({ id:  foo.bar.id, foos: [] })`. Then just push the `foo` in the `bar` list with `barsWithFoos[i - 1].foos.push({ id: foo.id })`:

```js
const foosWithBar = [  {id: 'Foo A',bar: { id: 'Bar 1', }, }, {    id: 'Foo B',    bar: {      id: 'Bar 1',    },  },  {    id: 'Foo C',   bar: {      id: 'Bar 2',    },  },  {   id: 'Foo D',   bar: {      id: 'Bar 2',    },  },];

const barsWithFoos = [];
foosWithBar.forEach(foo => {
  const i = barsWithFoos.findIndex(bar => bar.id === foo.bar.id) + 1 
            || barsWithFoos.push({ id:  foo.bar.id, foos: [] });
  barsWithFoos[i - 1].foos.push({ id: foo.id });
})

console.log(barsWithFoos);
```